# Does poster get notified by moderator comment on their deleted answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I've seen this on occassion, particularly with new users, where they post an answer which in itself is either a question or a comment. E.g.

> "I also experienced the same problem, would appreciate help. Thanks"

These kind of posts are normally flagged and users comment on how the OP should instead ask it as a new question.

But sometimes when nobody has commented, a moderator will add a comment and then almost immediately after, delete the post. In this instance, does the OP get notified of the moderator's comment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My understanding is that the user receives notification of the comment, and can still see their deleted post.

Certainly, when the action is taken on answers that are asking new questions (instead of answering the original question), the new question usually appears as a new question shortly thereafter.

Although the above evidence is circumstantial, I have no reason to suspect that the user does not receive the comment to notify them that their "answer" is being deleted.

I did a test with @Aaron just now where he commented on my other answer before deleting it and I received that comment, and was then able to see my deleted answer which had a link to [Why was your post deleted?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) automatically appended to.

[image]

---

More details about how exactly this works can be found at [How do notifications on deleted posts work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231668/215590)